# Free JSP obfuscator?

Tags: java, jsp, obfuscation, eclipse-wtp

I want to report a bug for the Eclipse WTP project which occurs on a JSP of my company's project but I don't want to attach the original jsp due to legal reasons.

Is there a way/free utility to obfuscate my jsp code easily?

Comment: I doubt that's what you want to do.  Obsfucated code is NOT going to be helpful in finding a bug until they actually follow the code and figure out what your proprietary secrets are, so you're just making work for yourself (and the Eclipse people... or would, if they didn't just ignore it).

Comment: what you have to do is: make a reproducible sample that doesn't include the original file, itself. If you are just hoping some eclipse developer to solve the issue for you, it aint happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to lacking answers I have to realize that there seems to be no obfuscator.

Comment: Eh? You were given two, and a reason not to use one at all.

Comment: @EJP: The "given two" are no jsp but java byte code obfuscators, hence are not answering my question.

Answer (score 6):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Either you want them to find the bug, which implies that they can understand the source code, or you want to conceal the source code, in which case you are impeding the fault report process.

What you *should* be doing is constructing a parallel case that exhibits the bug in the most minimal fashion possible and that doesn't give away your precious secrets. And if you can't do that, it is evidence that the bug is in your code. Which is by far the most likely possibility anyway.

Comment: Yes, this was also my solution due the lack of such a tool. I reduced the problematic jsp manually. But exactly this action (rename variables, delete text nodes etc) can be made by a tool which I was searching for so. So I don't see where my question contains a contradiction.

Comment: @MRalwasser: I have already explained where. To reiterate, obfuscation obscures the purpose of the code. A bug report needs to contain comprehensible code, at least if you want it to be acted on.

Comment: Not always. Consider a bug in a parser of an JSP Editor in an IDE which causes to throw a StackOverFlowError when just opening such a file. I don't think that it is required that the developer needs to understand what's going in my jsp in such a case. BTW, I submitted a "manual obfuscated" example. The WTP team was able to fix the bug.

Comment: @MRalwasser *of course* the developer needs to understand the source code, at least well enough to be able to parse it in his head and identify which construction is causing the stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

There is free jsp obfuscator:  [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.htm?gclid=CLHNvr3ft7ICFQu7zAodXBwAmQ) 
and an eclipse plugin : [obfuscate4e](http://sourceforge.net/projects/obfuscate4e/)

Comment: Both seem only to obfuscate java byte code, not jsps

Answer (score 1):

Try the [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), its a free Java class file shrinker and obfuscator. It can change the  names in your code using meaningless ones.

Comment: AFAIK, ProGuard obfuscates only **java** code, not **jsp** - or am I wrong?

Comment: @MRalwasser No, you're right, however you can precompile your jsps into java servlets, then use ProGuard on those Java classes.

Comment: @Riduidel but then the Eclipse WTP team will not be able to reproduce the bug in their jsp editor...

Comment: Up to the Documentation it can process WAR files which should enable this for JSP, search the usage for WAR files in http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/usage.html

Comment: @MRalwasser Then do what @bestsss advices you in the comment to your very question : create a simple reprductible test jsp that clearly exposes the bug.

Comment: Or, if you have a stack trace, at least give them that to work from.